# Не нажимается KeepOffet blender

Tags: анимация, blender

Я анимировал персонажа по одному очень популярному уроку (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsORkaq9MRo&t=654s), и на моменте где нужно было связать все кости при помощи Ctrl + P - Keef Offset, при нажатии на Keep Offset не происходит никакой реакции... Да и вообще не работает все меню "Сделать Родителем". Как именно выглядит проблема? Да так и выглядит! Жмешь, никакой реакции, меню не закрывается, кости не скрепляются. Как будто я ничего и не нажимал.

Answer (score 0):

Выделяешь все арматуры и ctrl+j
После чего также выделяешь как в уроке. Ctrl + P - Keep Offset.

В дальнейшем просто прокидывай кости в одном скелете, при нажатии shift + А, в режиме редактирования скелета создаётся новая кость.